# OpenCL - Storing a large array in private memory

Tags: opencl

I have a large array of `float` called `source_array` with the size of around 50.000. I am current trying to implement a collections of modifications on the array and evaluate it. Basically in pseudo code:

```
__kernel void doSomething (__global float *source_array, __global boolean *res. __global int *mod_value) {
     // Modify values of source_array with mod_value;
     // Evaluate the modified array.
}
```

So in the process I would need to have a variable to hold modified array, because `source_array` should be a constant for all work item, if i modify it directly it might interfere with another work item (not sure if I am right here).

The problem is the array is too big for private memory therefore I can't initialize in kernel code. What should I do in this case ?

I considered putting another parameter into the method, serves as place holder for modified array, but again it would intefere with another work items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private "memory" on GPUs literally consists of registers, which generally are in short supply. So the `__private` address space in OpenCL is not suitable for this as I'm sure you've found.

Victor's answer is correct - if you really need temporary memory for each work item, you will need to create a (global) buffer object. If all work items need to independently mutate it, it will need a size of `<WORK-ITEMS> * <BYTES-PER-ITEM>` and each work-item will need to use its own slice of the buffer. If it's only temporary, you never need to copy it back to host memory.

However, this sounds like an access pattern that will work very inefficiently on GPUs. You will do much better if you decompose your problem differently. For example, you may be able to make whole work-groups coordinate work on some subrange of the array - copy the subrange into local (group-shared) memory, the work is divided between the work items in the group, and the results are written back to global memory, and the next subrange is read to local, etc. Coordinating between work-items in a group is *much* more efficient than each work item accessing a huge range of global memory We can only help you with this algorithmic approach if you are more specific about the computation you are trying to perform.

Comment: I understand fully what you are saying, and creating such a big array with space for all items is not really a good idea. I will try like you said, decompose the problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Why not to initialize this array in OpenCL host memory buffer. I.e.

```
const size_t buffer_size = 50000 * sizeof(float);
/* cl_malloc, malloc or new float [50000] or = {0.1f,0.2f,...} */
float *host_array_ptr = (float*)cl_malloc(buffer_size);
/* 
    put your data into host_array_ptr hear 
*/
cl_int err_code;
cl_mem my_array = clCreateBuffer( my_cl_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, buffer_size, host_array_ptr, &err_code );
```

Then you can use this `cl_mem my_array` in OpenCL kernel

[Find out more](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html)

Comment: Would i work if i want to change the array values inside kernel code ? If its READ_ONLY then i can't do that right ?

Comment: Then when the work items are running parallel, they will make changes to the same object and therefore my evaluation on each work item will not be exact..

Comment: Off cause you can clone those buffers, synchronize access etc. I suppose the question was about storing large memory blocks outside the private memory. Some docs https://arrayfire.com/zero-copy-on-integrated-gpus/

Comment: I already know how to store the array in host or pass it into the kernel, the problem is i want to create an array to store the modified values of the array and use it for inside kernel method without saving it. I don't need it to be saved out of the scope of the method.

Comment: And how to perform this, if you physically have no memory in private vram ? You can use a host memory buffer internally inside the cl kernel, and this is a host application deal to manage this memory. Since you've done release it.